# Why does Celery deadlock when calling a chain of subtasks within a task?

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to create a nested task workflow in celery. Basically I have one main task that is first supposed to call a group of subtasks, wait for the results, then process them. Next it calls a chain of subtasks and does the same.

There is absolutely no issue executing the group of subtasks, the code keeps executing after results are returned. However, when I'm trying to execute the chain directly after it, the task seems to deadlock and nothing else happens.

I'm using celery 5.2.3

I've simplified what I'm trying to do in a contrived example here, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
@app.task(bind=True, args)
def main_task:
    parallel_task_args = list()
    sequential_task_args = list()

    for arg_num, arg in enumerate(args):
        parallel_task_args.append(__parallel_subtask.s(*arg))
        if arg_num == 0:
            sequential_task_args.append(__sequential_subtask.s(dict(), *arg))
        else:
            sequential_task_args.append(__sequential_subtask.s(*arg))
    
    parallel_task_results = group(*parallel_task_args).delay()
    with allow_join_result():
        parallel_task_results = parallel_task_results.get()
    ...

    sequential_task_results = chain(*sequential_task_args).delay()
    with allow_join_result():
        sequential_task_results = sequential_task_results.get()
    ...

@app.task()
def __parallel_subtask(arg)
    result = ...
    return result

@app.task()
def __sequential_subtask(signature, arg)
    if arg not in signature:
        signature[arg] = ...
    return signature
```

I’m aware that it’s bad practice to use results.get() inside another task, but I’d like to keep it as a workflow of subtasks if possible. How can I resolve the deadlock issue when calling the chain of subtasks within the main task?

**EDIT:**

Some background on the actual logic: I'm parsing a type of XML file as part of `main_task`. This file can potentially be very large (1GB at worst) so I would like to avoid having to parse it multiple times. `main_task` parses it once, then the subtasks run a number of analysis routines that give me IDs of elements in the file that should be deleted or edited. That's why I built the workflow this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the deadlock issue by executing the chain of subtasks as part of the main task's workflow using `chain` and `group`. In this way, you avoid calling `results.get()` inside the main task, which is the cause of the deadlock.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Would that mean creating a new chain in the main task from both the chain and group I currently have there? In that case, I'd have to implement intermediate steps that process the results of `__parallel_subtask ` and `__sequential_subtask`. The group results would normally be processed in the main task once the first group of parallel tasks finishes.